# parse boto output [Volume:vol-14235987, Volume:vol-1234567]

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

following boto command outputs as follows:

```
volumes=ec2Conn.get_all_volumes(filters={'attachment.instance-id': my_id})
```

Result

```
[Volume:vol-14235987, Volume:vol-1234567]
```

how can I parse this string, array output to produce just the volume-ID

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/2d7796a625f9596cbadb7d00c0198e5ed84631ed/boto/ec2/volume.py#L52) you can just ran `<YourVolumeInstance>.id`

Or in your case:

```
[x.id for x in [Volume:vol-14235987, Volume:vol-1234567]]
```

Answer (score 0):

use for loop

```
for volume in volumes:
  print volume.id

vol-14235987
vol-1234567
```

Answer (score 0):

Volumes here is an array of boto.ec2.volume objects,  that basically gives you access to all of its variable and methods

To obtain volume id you just have to use variable object.id.

```
for volume in volumes:
     print volume.id
```

Other variables available to you with this object are:

- id – The unique ID of the volume.
- create_time – The timestamp of when the volume was created.
- status – The status of the volume.
- size – size (in GB) of the volume.
- snapshot_id – The ID of the snapshot this volume was created from, if applicable.
- attach_data – An AttachmentSet object.
- zone – The availability zone this volume is in.
- type – The type of volume (standard or consistent-iops)
- iops – If this volume is of type consistent-iops, this is the number of IOPS provisioned (10-300).
- encrypted – True if this volume is encrypted.

read more here
http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.volume